# Bugzilla 4.2 new bug email

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bugzilla

I have installed bugzilla 4.2 and the New Bug email format has changed from bugzilla 3.6. I want to modify the summary list to display items in the order i want them. For example: in bugzilla 4.2 the order is Priority, Group, Bug ID, CC etc but i want them to be Bug #, Summary, Classification, Product etc.

Thanks in advance.